# Do jquery check always not only when page is being loaded

Tags: jquery

I need to check the value for one element when it is not empty but not only when page is being loaded. I need to do some action ALWAYS when that field is not empty. So currently my check looks like this

```
if(jQuery('.club_meter_maintext').html() !== '' && jQuery('.club_meter_maintext').html() !== '0' && jQuery('.club_meter_maintext').html() !== '----'){
     alert('Clubmeter is not empty');
}
```

Currently it does the alert only when page is being loaded, so it checks once and stops.

The thing is that am doing some actions with that same field and updating the value in concrete cases so i need a solution for this.

Any idea how i can do this check and do some action always when field is not empty?

Thanks.

Comment: you want to check every now and then? use setInterval

Comment: Put that code in a function and call it on load and in any event that affects the element. I'd also suggest you put the `html()` value in a variable as you're making three DOM scans to get the same value

Comment: @guradio with setinterval it will check from specific time but i need always when that field is empty

Comment: use events? which kind of element is it? you can add an key event or something like that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan re the variable yes i agree good advice but for adding that function in every place when value is being changed am a bit not happy as it will require more lines

Comment: @warch it is simple span with value inside

Comment: Read about **MutationObserver** patterns.
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/

Comment: could you please provide fiddle for this ?

Comment: Try to use `||` instead of `&&` in your condition may be solve your issue..

Comment: @SunilKumar with || conditon is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is over 2 months old, however I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (($.trim($(".club_meter_maintext").html()) !== '') && ($.trim($(".club_meter_maintext").html()) !== '0') && ($.trim($(".club_meter_maintext").html()) !== '----')) {    
    alert('Clubmeter is not empty');
}

});
```

Since Chrome & FF consider white-spaces and line-breaks as elements it would be a good idea to use "$.trim" otherwise you can take it out.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a input field:

Bind the check to the onChange event of the field

If not:

Add a timer and call the check function every 1 ms. This generates heavy CPU load but this will trigger the check nearly always.